# pymong group and count

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

let say I have a collection with some log entries (50^6), that I would like to be abble to prompt in order to extract some satistics.

here is an example of one of the document in my collection. I just left the relevant informations

```
{
  'prg': 'blastall', 
  'uid': '7225',
  'version': '2.2.21',
  'date': datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 1, 0, 0),
  '_id': ObjectId('54948dbdff4346034c23ae8d'), 
  'pack': 'blast'
}
```

note that various prg may pertains to one package

I would like to be abble to extract for a given couple of package/version the following informatin.
nb of ocuurences in the collection 
list of the uid that used this package/version 
list of the used prog

currently I doing it this way.

satrt, end are datetimes that restrict the period interval to deal with.

```
pack_ag = col.aggregate([
    {'$match': {"date": {'$gte':start, '$lt': end}}},
    {'$project' : {'pack':1, 'version':1, 'prg':1, 'uid':1}},
    {'$group' :{"_id":{"pack":"$pack", "version":"$version"}, 'hits': {'$sum': 1}, 'progs': { '$addToSet': "$prg"}, 'users': {'$addToSet': '$uid'}}}])
```

it gives me something as expected ;-)

```
{
  'progs': ['blastall', 'formatdb', 'megablast'], 
  'hits': 1212,
  '_id': {'version': '2.2.21', 'pack': 'blast'}, 
  'users': ['7225', '1234', '9876]
}
```

what I would like to be abble is to store in the progs list  the information of program usage.
eg get something like:

```
progs': [{'blastall': 1000}, {'formatdb': 200}, {'megablast':12}]
```

I must admit that curently I don't know how to perform the task in an other way than looping on the results, find and count the documents that match pack/version/prg followed by an update of the document.

is there a way to fullfill this at the momgo query level ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely aggregate the result, not exactly in the expected format as:

```
progs': [{'blastall': 1000}, {'formatdb': 200}, {'megablast':12}]
```

but very close to that which definitely will be useful and easily retrievable.

- To get the count of the unique `programs` for a combination of `pack`
  and `version`, `group`, the records on `pack`, `version` and `prg`.
  The `$sum` operator in each group will give the count of each unique
  `prg`. Hold the reference to the list of records for each `prg`.
- Now unwind the grouped records based on `rec` field.
- Project `prg_detail` as an object holding the name of the `prg` and
  its count for each record.
- Group the un-winded records back by only `pack` and `version`
  attributes, and accumulate the users and progs items as unique lists.

Modified Code:

```
col.aggregate([
{$match: {"date": {$gte:start, $lt: end}}},
{$group:{"_id":{"pack":"$pack","version":"$version","prg":"$prg"},
         "count":{$sum:1},"rec":{$push:"$$ROOT"}}},
{$unwind:"$rec"},
{$project:{"pack":"$_id.pack","version":"$_id.version",
           "prg_detail":{"name":"$_id.prg","count":"$count"},"rec":1}},
{$group:{"_id":{"pack":"$pack",
                "version":"$version"},
         "progs":{$addToSet:"$prg_detail"},
         "hits":{$sum:1},
         "users":{$addToSet:"$rec.uid"}}}])
```

Sample o/p:

```
{
        "_id" : {
                "pack" : "blast",
                "version" : "2.2.21"
        },
        "progs" : [
                {
                        "name" : "blastall",
                        "count" : 1
                },
                {
                        "name" : "formatDB",
                        "count" : 2
                },
                {
                        "name" : "megaBlast",
                        "count" : 1
                }
        ],
        "hits" : 4,
        "users" : [
                "7225",
                "7229",
                "7226",
                "7227"
        ]
}
```